# Get unique identifier for android device which is common across multiple applications

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been using

```
Android.Gms.Ads.Identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.GetAdvertisingIdInfo(ApplicationContext).Id;
```

To get a unique identifier common across the device for multiple applications.

But now, since 1st April 2022, Android has changed its policies.

I have already used

```
Secure.GetString(context.ContentResolver, Secure.AndroidId)
UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

This gives a different ID for every other application.

Can anybody suggest getting a unique device identifier that is common across the device, even for multiple applications?

Comment: I know nothing about Android's API, but I'd expect that `UUID.randomUUID()` would, well, give me a random UUID.

Comment: [App Set ID (Identify developer-owned apps)](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/app-set-id).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have already seen this option, but we are saving the ID in the backend for user device identification. the article says "developers shouldn't rely on a cached value of the app set ID."
So will not be able to use this.

Comment: IMHO, expected usage is that you read the ID while in one of your apps, store it in backend (your server), then when user opens another of your apps, you read the ID there, and send it to backend to match. This allows you to ask user to login (with an account and password maintained on your server) in one app, then not have to login again for any app - unless they delete all apps by your company. OR something changes at OS level, causing App Set IDs to be regenerated for all apps. It may not be what you are hoping for, but it is better than nothing. And is consistent with current Privacy Laws.

Comment: It reduces how often a user needs to login. Should be able to go a long time before anything changes that requires a login on your apps on their device. (Though I have not used it myself, since I have not done multiple related apps.)

Comment: If your license terms do not permit a user to login simultaneously on multiple devices, then if you see a login from a device with a different ID, you disable access for that account on any previously registered ID.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve We are already having the multiple device mechanism implemented, but since we have multiple applications, so we are looking a device identifier which can be specific to that device and allow the user to login just once and access other apps as well.
The solution which you have mentioned above is the one we are considering right now, but it will take time for implementation and integration, so meanwhile we are looking for other options as well